# Matlab - Constrained Optimisation

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix

I have a `15`-by-`15` matrix `A` with set of values. I have an another `15`-by-`1` matrix `B` with set of values

Resultant, C=(transpose(B)*A)* A;
D= 30/C;

My objective function is to maximize `D` by changing the values of matrix `B` subject to the following constraints

1. The values of `15`-by-`1` matrix, `B`, should be between upper and lower bound. The matrix `B` is imagined to be split into upper half of `10` elements and lower half of `5` elements
2. The number of elements whose value changes in the upper half of matrix `B` should be less than or equal to `3`
3. The number of elements whose value changes in the lower half of matrix `B` should be less than or equal to `2`

Experts, I need some help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please first try this solution yourself, at least get to a point where you have written out your objective function (i.e. your Resultant) in MATLAB syntax and set up the problem using `fmincon` even if you don't get your constraints right...

Comment: I have added the MATLAB code

function [D] = fun1(A,B)
C = (transpose(A)*B)* A;
C = sqrt(C);
D = (30)/C;
D = -1*D;

f = @(weights) fun1(W,C);
[Out1,Out2,Out3]= fmincon(f,R,A,B,Aeq,Beq,ILB,IUB,[],options);